# remove hash process in laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.3

I'm building an application for a free radius management user hotspot, I've changed the default login laravel from the user to radcheck. but when the registration process using encryption bcrypt I can login, but otherwise if I remove bcrypt process I can not log in and find error in email input like

> These credentials do not match our records.

in register controller

```
  protected function create(array $data)
{
    $radcheck = Radcheck::create([
        'username' => $data['username'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'value' => $data['value'],
    ]);

    $memberRole = Role::where('name','=','member')->first();
    $radcheck->attachRole($memberRole);
    return $radcheck;
}
```

and I didn't change the file logincontroller.php

if anyone can help me?
thanks so much for help me

Comment: What do you mean by "when the registration process using encryption bcrypt I can login"

Answer (score 0):

You may want to read about [authenticating users manually](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#authenticating-users) and `Auth::login()` method:

```
// Login user.
Auth::login($user);

// Login and remember the given user.
Auth::login($user, true);
```